# How do I add a reference to a project to avoid extra downloads

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, visual-studio-express

I can't seem to find the solution I'm looking for in the similar questions, but that might be because of my lack of searching skills.

Either way, I have a `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` in my C# project which I use to unzip a downloaded .zip file.

My problem arises from the following: I hate installers... Thus I need a way to include the `Interop.Shell32.dll` file into the .exe which is located in the project's \bin\Debug folder.

Thus avoiding the need for an installer which adds the Interop.Shell32.dll into the program's path and avoiding the need for an extra file download along with the .exe if I don't use an installer.

What would be the best/most efficient way for me to do so? (Preferably without having to include a load of extra code into the program)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx

Comment: Have you thought about adding your zip file as a resource into your project?

Comment: @Sam No, because the zip file is going to change in the future (the zip file will be getting extra content)

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's possible, but you could just download the new version of your file and then replace the old version resource with the new one.

Comment: @SLaks for some reason I'm not able to use the ZipFile class, not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not. Sam, I suppose that would be another option, but that still doesn't solve the problem I'm having, which is the .dll not being included in the .exe file.

Comment: If you [embed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource) the dll, then it will be a single file.

Comment: If you mean embedding it as a resource, then that's my first thought, but then how would I use it as a reference in my project?

Comment: Just follow the link i previously posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several useful tools; I'm not exactly sure what is being sought, so I will provide a small listing of tools/approaches that I use.

1. [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) for merging multiple *managed assemblies* such as the project output and external assemblies/PIAs. Make sure the PIA/assembly being merged is allowed to be distributable as such or see #3.
2. Embedded resources for including "external data" including *non-managed* DLLs which might be external requirements for managed assemblies. These *non-managed* DLLs/COM libraries can be bound/loaded at runtime after extraction.
3. [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com) for making a *unified launcher/installer* (it is a bootstrap and can provide embedded resources). This can be used in conjunction with a normal MSI (VS Setup Project) installer to handle prerequisites such as installing official distributable packages *or* it could simply be used to launch the executable (no "installer" except those for prerequisites).

Comment: The exact thing I'm looking for would be a way to embed the Interop.Shell32.dll file in the project, the only way I can think of would be by using it as an embedded resource, but then how would I add that resource as a reference?

Comment: @Yorrick If Interop.Shell32.dll is a PIA (and singly distributable) then ILMerge is the easiest way. The namespace/resource will be found by the fusion loader, just as though it was "built into" the current project.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by PIA, but the .dll comes standard (as far as I can tell) with visual studio, I've called the reference in my project by using `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: PIA - Primary Interop Assembly (usually Interop.* :-). PIAs are Managed Assemblies created by the "owner" of said DLL/COM and should work fine (assuming that the underlying native DLL/COM is available). ILMerge works with all *managed assemblies* I have tried it with. So add the reference for Interop.Shell32 to the Project and then use ILMerge *after* the project is built to make a single unified exec. There is a nuget package (two, actually) for ILMerge.

Comment: So, you would suggest ILMerge before using it as an embedded resource? Just making sure I'm not misunderstanding you here :)

Comment: @Yorrick For *managed assemblies*, absolutely! Using an embedded resource would be for packaging/distributing a *native* DLL or similar (perhaps one that was used by said ILMerged managed code).

Comment: Just making sure I've got this part right though, by "after the project is built", you do mean "after I've run debug mode, thus making the new .exe in the \Debug\bin\", correct? I'm a bit tired so I just want to have everything perfectly understood by myself before actually trying a solution :D

Comment: @Yorrick ILMerge takes in multiple *managed* DLL/EXE files (e.g. project output and Interop.Shell32) and creates a single *managed* DLL/EXE. See the usage guide (linked in other answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630). Taken from the Microsoft webpage:

> ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output.